Ramda - propEq from a list
I am new to Ramda and i am trying to find out element that us matching the given property key and property value. Below one works for me.
R.find(R.propEq('propertyName', 'propertyVal'));

However, what i am looking for is the propertyName from a given list. I mean i need a function that looks up for the elements from possbile list.. something like below
R.find(R.propEq('propertyName', ['propertyVal1', 'propertyVal2']

Please suggest what function should be used here to find elements by possible property values

Can you clarify how you expect R.propEq('propertyName', ['propertyVal1', 'propertyVal2']) to work? Do you want it to be true if propertyName equals either propertyVal1 OR propertyVal2? Or do you expect it to return true if propertyName value equals the array ['propertyVal1', 'propertyVal2'], or something else?

yes.. i was looking for R.propEq('propertyName', ['propertyVal1', 'propertyVal2']) to return true if propertyName value is from the given possible list of values..

Basically, i was looking for similar condition of propEq, however, i wanted to pass list of values here (instead a singe value)...

I'd recommend to flip R.includes


const list = [
  { name: 'Apple' },
  { name: 'Banana' },
  { name: 'Avocado' }
];

const fruit = R.filter(
  R.propSatisfies(R.includes(R.__, ['Banana', 'Apple']), 'name'),
);

console.log(
  fruit(list),
)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.30.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-FHBrUNR2Aspc5CQI8/3KQAmtud6erZKGG+BBdT5EqL2i1OcKP9POVu2ZLVDAMxmoc7go1kIWnq6WzmRjdsOxTw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



